# JSLint integration with TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, jslint

I'm setting up TeamCity as my build server.

I have my project set up, it is updating correctly from subversion, and building ok.

Now I want to use JSLint for js code analysis. I don't know how can I run JSLint from TeamCity?

Is there any plugin available for this?

So if anybody used JSLint in TeamCity? Help me.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll want something like this:

http://css.dzone.com/articles/teamcity-javascript

Which demonstrates how to add the JS inspections by initially setting up a Inspection Profile using one of the JetBrains intelligent IDEs. Then you can fail your build based off warnings / errors.

I'm not sure if you could use the community edition of the Java IDE or if you would need to use the thirty day trial to set it up of any of them.

Comment: This is not really applicable if you do not use JetBrains IDE for your project.  And there are no other suggestions how to use JSLint\JSHint offline..